# ASP.NET site map configuration error

Tags: .net, asp.net, sitemap

I have received this error, but don't know what it means:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Exactly one `<siteMapNode>` element is required directly inside the `<siteMap>` element.

Can you help me?

Comment: upvoted. Even if the question seem simple, no question is too simple for SO.com

Comment: Agree w/ @Maxim - Welcome to Stack Overflow mohammad.  I hope you'll find the community helpful in your ASP.NET endeavours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be something with sitemap... I googled and found this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1245553.aspx

> The site map has to have a single root
>   siteMapNode element, underneath which
>   all other elements reside. So you
>   have:
>
> ```
> <siteMap>
>     <siteMapNode title="Home" ...>
>         all other nodes
>     </siteMapNode>
> </siteMap>
> ```
>
> This means that all nodes are at least
>   a child of the root node. When
>   displaying the Menu you can chose to
>   not show the root node, or to show
>   both it and the child nodes together.

Comment: In SiteMapDataSource, property ShowStartingNode : False.

Answer (score 2):

If  you are building menu from sitemap and you don't want to have all menu items in one node, then you can hide starting node in SiteMapDataSource with attribute

```
ShowStartingNode="false"
```

For example:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="MainMenuSiteMap" SiteMapProvider="MainMenuProvider" ShowStartingNode="false" runat="server" /`>
```